# How to Concat() dataframe having 1 row with dataframe having multiple rows in Python

Tags: python, concatenation, python-3.8

[df1 result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyJg6.png)

[df2 result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHED7.png)

I need to concatenate columns from df1 and df2.
for each row in df2, df1 columns will be concatenated

[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vn20d.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)...[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) ... 
[You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Your question is too broad. Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Please include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it to the question. Also make sure to read [How do I ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these are represented as Pandas data frames, the following should return the concatenated data frame you're looking for:

`result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join="inner")`

Comment: It is printing only 1 row. Needs to concat df1 with all rows in df2